# OxyPlot change axes

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

I draw data using oxyplot. The axes are autoscaling, therefore the properties, Minimum and Maximum are NaN for each axis. But I want to see a certain area of this plot. I can not use the zoom because it only allows me to set a zoomlevel, which would differ for different dataset, since autoscale is on.

Straight forward, I would change the ActualMinimum and ActualMaximum property, which actually would do exactly what I need. These properties are not settable.

How to do?

Comment: I think a little bit of code of what you have done will help.

Comment: Have you tried giving a value to Minimum and maximum properties of the axes? this modifies the other 2 properties that you have said(ActualMinimum and ActualMaximum). You can always restore the double.NaN value if you want to set autoscaling again.

Comment: You need to set the zoom. Let's say your axis is `lAxis` do `lAxis.Zoom(max, min);` When you switch to a different dataset, you have to recalculate your min and max and set the zoom again.

Answer (score 3):

Found a fix!
Instead of using Maximum and Minimum, I should have used Axis.Zoom:

```
plotModel.Axes[1].Zoom(100, 500);
```